# I'm looking to add a page of order meta before woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta

I have set up a function on my billing/shipping page for woocommerce where the user selects a few items based on a custom loop.

I was wondering if it is possible to add a page before the cart page so process will be as follows:

1. Choose items from custom loop
2. press 'proceed to cart'(already hooked up to add the specific product)
3. press 'proceed to checkout'
4. On successful payment the information they chose on step 1 will show in their order on the backend and in the email.

I already have step 4 working but step 1 is actually on the checkout page. I need to move it to a page before the cart.

Is there a hook that I can use? Currently I am using

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );
```

Thanks